# How do I find my Facebook messages from within a certain time period?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I need to find messages from December 2013 to May 2016. I lost my daughter in December 2013 and forgot a lot of things.

Comment: For my answer, I assumed you are asking how to view your instant messages. If that is not what you are asking about, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

At the top of the Facebook website is a blue bar, and towards the right side of that are several icons. Click on the icon that looks like two overlapping speech bubbles. At the bottom of the box that pops up, there will be a link reading "See All"; click that. You arrive at the Messages inbox. Click on any name in the list on the left to view conversations you have had with people.

Unfortunately, you won't be able to get just the messages within the time range you desire, but you can keep scrolling up in the conversation window to view progressively older messages.